# How to display full column name in dataframe while using streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, streamlit

I'm new to streamlit and trying to display a dataframe.

The problem is that some column names are not fully displayed because of the value of the item is short.

[image]

above is an example picture.

the **second column** is shortened. I'm able to manually stretch the column, though I want to know if it's possible automatically.

Is there a way to display the full column name?

Comment: related issue https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/371

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***streamlit AgGrid Component*** to fix that problem. `AgGrid()` by default will will take care of that.

In case you want to know more about AgrGrid [visit streamlit AgGrid Component](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components).

**Installation:** `pip install streamlit-aggrid`

```py
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

AgGrid(df)
```